# Python clean text file to make it searchable

Tags: python, numpy, data-cleaning

I have a very messy text file that consist of both comma and space seperated data that looks like the following:

```
NBLOCK,3,,13
(1i9,3e20.9e3)
        1     4.000000000E+01    -6.000000000E+01     0.000000000E+00
        2     4.000000000E+01     6.000000000E+01     0.000000000E+00
        3     4.000000000E+01    -2.000000000E+01     0.000000000E+00
        4     4.000000000E+01     2.000000000E+01     0.000000000E+00
```

I need to clean up the file such that I get an easily searchable 2d array using the following rules:

- make letters lower case
- delete repeating spaces
- replace spaces by commas
- delete comma if line is starting with a comma
- convert to numpy 2d array

The output should look something like the following

```
my_array = [['nblock','3','','13'],
['(1i9','3e20.9e3)','',''],
['1','4.000000000e+01','-6.000000000e+01','0.000000000e+00'],
['2','4.000000000e+01','6.000000000e+01','0.000000000e+00'],
['3','4.000000000e+01','-2.000000000e+01','0.000000000e+00'],
['4','4.000000000e+01','2.000000000e+01','0.000000000e+00']]
```

**Update more realistic example of text file:**

```
ET,       1, 42
KEYOP,   1, 2,        1
KEYOP,   1, 3,        3
RLBLOCK,       1,       1,       6,       7
N,R5.3,LOC, -1,
NBLOCK,3,,13
(1i9,3e20.9e3)
1     4.000000000E+01    -6.000000000E+01     0.000000000E+00
        2     4.000000000E+01     6.000000000E+01     0.000000000E+00
        3     4.000000000E+01    -2.000000000E+01     0.000000000E+00
        4     4.000000000E+01     2.000000000E+01     0.000000000E+00
-1
MPTEMP,R5.0, 1, 1,  0.00000000    ,
MPDATA,R5.0, 1,EX  ,       1, 1, 2.100000000E+11,
MPTEMP,R5.0, 1, 1,  0.00000000    ,
MPDATA,R5.0, 1,NUXY,       1, 1, 0.300000000    ,
MPTEMP,R5.0, 1, 1,  0.00000000    ,
MPDATA,R5.0, 1,DENS,       1, 1,  7800.00000    ,
MPTEMP,R5.0, 1, 1,  0.00000000    ,
MPDATA,R5.0, 1,PRXY,       1, 1, 0.300000000    ,
EXTOPT,ATTR,  0,  0,  0
EXTOPT,ESIZE,  0,  0.0000    
EXTOPT,ACLEAR,  0
BFUNIF,TEMP,_TINY
```

Another example:

```
DMPOPT,EMAT,NO
*IF,_CDRDOFF,EQ,1,THEN     !if solid model was read in
_CDRDOFF=             !reset flag, numoffs already performed
*ELSE              !offset database for the following FE model
NUMOFF,NODE,       12
NUMOFF,ELEM,        8
NUMOFF,MAT ,        1
NUMOFF,REAL,        1
NUMOFF,TYPE,        2
NUMOFF,CSYS,       12
*ENDIF
KUSE,     0
TIME,  0.00000000
NBLOCK,6,SOLID,        12,        12
(3i9,6e21.13e3)
        1        0        0 4.0000000000000E+001-6.0000000000000E+001
        2        0        0 4.0000000000000E+001 6.0000000000000E+001
        3        0        0 4.0000000000000E+001-2.0000000000000E+001
        4        0        0 4.0000000000000E+001 2.0000000000000E+001   
EBLOCK,19,SOLID,    1250
(19i8)
       1       1       1       1
       1       1       1       1       
       1       1       1       1
-1
N,R5.3,LOC,     -1,
MPDATA,R5.0, 1,EX  ,       1, 1, 2.100000000E+11,
MPTEMP,R5.0, 1, 1,  0.00000000    ,
MPDATA,R5.0, 1,NUXY,       1, 1, 0.300000000    ,
MPTEMP,R5.0, 1, 1,  0.00000000    ,

MPDATA,R5.0, 1,DENS,       1, 1,  7800.00000    ,
MPTEMP,R5.0, 1, 1,  0.00000000    ,
MPDATA,R5.0, 1,PRXY,       1, 1, 0.300000000
```

Comment: Surely you want those as integers or floats, and not strings.  Right?  The numeric data could become a numpy array, but the header can't.

Comment: No ideally I would want everything as strings initially. The file I am working with needs to be searched for keywords like nblock and others after I have it in a somewhat readable format. Afterwards I will convert the relevant numbers to floats.

Comment: But "NBLOCK" always introduces that array, right?  What I'm saying is to treat those names as attributes.  Create an object (or dict) with an `NBLOCK` attribute that contains the translated data, and `MPTEMP` and `MPDATA` elements with a list of items.  Do you see what I mean?  There's no point in "searching" for NBLOCK.  You know it's in there.  You should just be able to reference `object.nblock` or `object['NBLOCK']`.  What I show below is just the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this kind of solution:

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

class Block:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
        self.array = []

    def ingest(self, lines):
        for line in lines:
            if 'A' <= line[0] <= 'Z':
                parts = [k.strip() for k in line.split(',')]
                parts = [int(k) if k.isdigit() else k for k in parts]
                key = parts[0].lower()
                if key not in self.data:
                    self.data[key] = [parts[1:]]
                else:
                    self.data[key].append( parts[1:] )
            elif line[0] == '(':
                self.data['nblock'].append( [line.strip().split(',')] )
                self.data['nblock'].append( [] )
            else:
                parts = line.split()
                if parts[0] != '-1':
                    self.data['nblock'][2].append( [float(k) for k in parts[1:]] )

blk = Block()
blk.ingest( open('x.txt') )
pprint(blk.data)
```

Output:

```
{'bfunif': [['TEMP', '_TINY']],
 'et': [[1, 42]],
 'extopt': [['ATTR', 0, 0, 0], ['ESIZE', 0, '0.0000'], ['ACLEAR', 0]],
 'keyop': [[1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3]],
 'mpdata': [['R5.0', 1, 'EX', 1, 1, '2.100000000E+11', ''],
            ['R5.0', 1, 'NUXY', 1, 1, '0.300000000', ''],
            ['R5.0', 1, 'DENS', 1, 1, '7800.00000', ''],
            ['R5.0', 1, 'PRXY', 1, 1, '0.300000000', '']],
 'mptemp': [['R5.0', 1, 1, '0.00000000', ''],
            ['R5.0', 1, 1, '0.00000000', ''],
            ['R5.0', 1, 1, '0.00000000', ''],
            ['R5.0', 1, 1, '0.00000000', '']],
 'n': [['R5.3', 'LOC', '-1', '']],
 'nblock': [[3, '', 13],
            [['(1i9', '3e20.9e3)']],
            [[40.0, -60.0, 0.0],
             [40.0, 60.0, 0.0],
             [40.0, -20.0, 0.0],
             [40.0, 20.0, 0.0]]],
 'rlblock': [[1, 1, 6, 7]]}
```

Note that I've provided a string lines iterator, but you could also pass a file.  Anything that will iterate through a list of strings.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work. The file im working with is a lot more complicated than the example I have provided and needs to be searched for keywords after it is in a readable format. I have updated the original post more a better example.

Comment: I still think my approach is the right one.  Here, I'm creating a dictionary entry for each keyword and gathering the members.  You could do a little more processing to convert the float values, but now you can search this dictionary by keyword to find what you want.

Comment: This is a very nice solution but I am seeing a couple of issues that I am not able to fix in your code. 

1) When I have an empty line in the text document the code does not run.

2) The way you add values to the nblock array will not work for the full document. I have multiple variables (ex: nblock and eblock). where the values are stored in a similiar manner, i.e first line afterward the name has variable info and then the following lines contain the data.

The first entrance of the nblock data increments by 1 for each line and the first entrance of eblock data is always 1.

Comment: I have added another example in the post

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to write the app for you.  I'm trying to show you an approach.  Empty lines are easy to handle.  What you have there is a programming language, including conditionals.  You still haven't given us a clue about what you expect to DO with this data.

Comment: All the help is very much apreciated. Yes it is some kind of programming language, it is an input file generated by ANSYS finite element program that describes the finite element model setup. I am trying to read all the data such that I can essentially generate the elements in ANSYS and then run my own finite element code on the data. I am new to programming and this is just a hobby project for me but I have almost got a working finite element code and mainly just missing a way to automatically generate the element setup.

Comment: OK, good.  In that case, you will need you have your own internal data structure representation of the model, and your job will be to import this file into your model.  You will end up with something like what I have done, but smarter.  Just taking it into numpy as raw string rows, is not productive.